# Python 3.5.0 :::: Entering keys and values in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I know this is a very basic question but still a problem I need to solve and do not know the answer.

So I want to put entries in a dictionary:

I have a variable that is a dictionary and I want to insert keys and values such that the key's names vary as x goes down:

```
x = 2
dic= dict()
while x >0:
    dic["row" x] = '0'
    x -= 1
print (dic)
```

And the output is:

```
{("row", 2): 0, ("row", 1): 0, ("row", 0): 0}
```

I want it to be:

```
{row 2: 0, row 1: 0, row 0: 0}
```

Can you explain me how to remove the parentheses and the comas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format` function should do it.

```
while x > 0:
    dic["row {}".format(x)] = '0'
    x -= 1
```

Comment: But know gives me this output: 'gulliver': (15, 45, 'fail'), but I want to remove the parentheses in the values so that the result is: 'gulliver': 15, 45, 'fail'. How do I do that?

Comment: @InêsBarataFeioBorges You cant remove the parentheses; they indicate that the value is a tuple. Those values need a container of some kind, else how will you refer to them?